# SQL Server 2008 Maintenance Plan Failure

Tags: sql-server-2008, index-tuning

Instead of using my old school index rebuild script I had decided to use 2008's built-in Maintenance Plan to do a simple Rebuild Index task.

The details are:

- Connection = Local server connection
- Databases = Specific databases (just one)
- Object = Tables and Views
- Free space options = I have tried both default amount and change percentage to 70%
- Advanced options = Keep index online while reindexing is the only one checked.  This is the primary reason I wanted to use this was to see if we could keep an index online while still doing the rebuild.

When I run the T-SQL from this manually everything works ok, but I assume it is not keeping the index online.  Whenever I run the job though I get this very strange error that has not led me anywhere:

> *Executing the query "ALTER INDEX [Agreement_PK] ON [dbo].[Agreement]
>    RE..." failed with the following error: "String or binary data would
>    be truncated. The statement has been terminated.". Possible failure
>    reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>    correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>    correctly.*

```
USE [<dbase>]
GO
ALTER INDEX [Agreement_PK] ON [dbo].[Agreement] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( FILLFACTOR = 30, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ONLINE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF ) 
GO
USE [<dbase>] 
GO
ALTER INDEX [IX_Agreement_1] ON [dbo].[Agreement] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( FILLFACTOR = 30, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ONLINE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF ) 
GO
```

The T-SQL is very generic and gives no indication as to what isn't set correctly or why such a simple local connection would be a problem.  EDIT: Here is that code from my comment.

It is set to use Windows NT Integrated security, but I am not sure why that would be a problem again on a local system connection.

Comment: What does the schema of the Agreement table look like?

Answer (score 1):

You have "SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF" when running the code as T_SQL

When running the job this setting must be different.

Comment: Ummm I don't think so.  Here is an example of the code: USE [<dbase>]
GO
ALTER INDEX [Agreement_PK] ON [dbo].[Agreement] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( FILLFACTOR = 30, PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, ONLINE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF )
GO
USE [<dbase>]
GO
ALTER INDEX [IX_Agreement_1] ON [dbo].[Agreement] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( FILLFACTOR = 30, PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, ONLINE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF )
GO

Comment: @maczealot - Post this code into your question if it is relevant.  There we can read it better. :) Also, I do not see any explicit `ANSI_WARNINGS` setting here, so your job may be defaulting to `OFF` as Jimbo suggested. What happens when you add `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;` to the beginning of your code?

Comment: Ok, I put that text into my OP and tried running the T-SQL with a `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;` at the beginning and as usual it all completed successfully with (1 row(s) affected) etc.  Even if I uncheck the keep-index-online option in the MP it still fails with the "String or binary data would be truncated" thanks again for looking at this problem and for any guidance!